# Scheduled job "Geocode and Parse Addresses" fails with error "Unknown api version"

Tags: geocoding

Started getting this error immediately after upgrading from 5.65 to 5.67. The daily job now fails consistently.

The .log in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog makes no reference to the job name or to the error. The closest thing in the log is "[warning] hook_civicrm_geofill_parser should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke()" but that has been coming up for a long time and only when an address (USPS) is sanitized and geocoded in the GUI, which continues to work properly.

Drupal 7's admin/reports/dblog doesn't show anything that correlates.

The Geocode provider is Google. The Google Cloud Platform Metrics data isn't showing any errors, though my ability to read that is suspect since I can only find three queries reported in the last 30 days (all successful, all before the CiviCRM upgrade).

Google is also the mapping provider and mapping contacts in CiviCRM continues to work.

Solutions would be great, but I'd be happy for suggestions to continue tracking down the source of the problem. Preferably detailed suggestions, assuming I know my way around is optimistic!

| Component | Version |
| --- | --- |
| PHP | 7.4.33 |
| DB | MariaDB 5.5.5-10.6.16 |
| CMS | Drupal 7.97 |
| CiviCRM | 5.67.1 |
| Geodata Filler | 1.0.0-alpha1 |

Answer (score 1):

If you've been on Civi for a while, the job might not have all the required parameters. I just fixed this on a site by changing the parameters on the job from

```
geocoding=1
throttle=1
```

to

```
geocoding=1
parse=0
throttle=1
```

(Adding `parse=0` to the parameters)

Comment: According to the docs that'd mean giving up on parsing. Big loss! [https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_geocode ]